# Angular app not detecting changes when running cypress tests

Tags: angular, cypress, e2e-testing

I have an interesting problem while running Cypress tests against my angular app.

The issue I am seeing is that DOM is not responding to changes from observables or component values when I am running my cypress tests.

Here is a really simple example of what I am seeing.

In my component I have the following.

component.html

```html
<button
  mat-raised-button
  color="primary"
  (click)="toggleGemVersion()"
  data-cy="serverspecs-hide-show-current-gem-version-btn">
  Toggle Version
</button>

<div *ngIf="!hideGem">
  <p data-cy="serverspecs-current-gem-version">{{ gemVersion$ | async }}</p>
</div>
```

component.ts

```js
hideGem = true;
gemVersion$: Observable<string> = this.store.pipe(select(getGemVersion));

toggleGemVersion() {
  this.hideGem = !this.hideGem;
}
```

cypress.spec.ts

```js
it('should toggle the current gem version when the show/hide button is clicked', () => {
  // Click the show/hide current gem version button
  cy.get('[data-cy=serverspecs-hide-show-current-gem-version-btn]')
    .should('be.visible')
    .click();

  // Cypress test fails here saying this element doesn't exist
  cy.get('[data-cy=serverspecs-current-gem-version]')
    .should('exist')
    .should('have.value', '2.175.0');

  // Click the show/hide current gem version button
  cy.get('[data-cy=serverspecs-hide-show-current-gem-version-btn]')
    .should('be.visible')
    .click();

  // Verify current gem version is not showing
  cy.get('[data-cy=serverspecs-current-gem-version]').should('not.exist');
});
```

When I `console.log` the value of `this.hideGem` in the `toggleGemVersion` function I am seeing the correct value displayed in the cypress window console but I am not seeing those changes reflected in the dom.

Is there something I need to do in my angular config to get DOM changes to happen when running a cypress test?

Another interesting note, I exposed the `ChangeDetectorRef` service to the `window` variable and when I run `win.cd.detectChanges();` from the cypress tests after the cypress `click()` events the tests pass.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case I used `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` for my component and did not use `ChangeDetectorRef`.

To fix it you have to inject `ChangeDetectorRef` to your component and update your `toggleGemVersion` method:

```
toggleGemVersion() {
  this.hideGem = !this.hideGem;
  this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: The only problem I have with this is that it is a rather inconvenient change to have to make to every component you want to test just so that cypress tests work 